# Keep deleted data in subselect to insert afterwards

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a possible way to update an existing table with a group by summary of the same table?

Example:

**Table A**

```
data (decimal(5,2)) | id (int) | year (date)
```

In table A there are many records like

```
1.05 | 1 | 31.11.2015

10 | 1 | 31.11.2015
...
```

I now want to `group by ID & YEAR` and only have those records in table A.

```
11.5 | 1 | 31.11.2015
...
```

Is there a way to achieve this, without a copy of the table A? Like can I store a complete resultset in an variable, then truncate the table and insert the new ones grouped by in table A?

Comment: Use a `select into #TempResult`, Truncate your table and reinsert the values from your temporary result...

Comment: Just for info : I your example you have given the date as `31.11.2015` which is 31st day of November. There is not a date such.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thanks that was what I needed. If u could post ur comment again as an answer I will mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `select into #TempResult`, Truncate your table and reinsert the values from your temporary result...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `truncate` the `tableA` and insert the new result set to tableA, then store the new result set to a temporary table, truncate tableA and then insert data from temp table to tableA.

**Query**

```
select sum(data) as data,
id,[year]
into #tbl
from tableA
group by id,[year];

truncate table tableA;

insert into tableA(data,id,[year])
select data,id,[year] from #tbl;

drop table #tbl;

select * from tableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should calculate `SUM(data) GROUP BY ID, Year`, you can use [Window functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) (SQL Server 2005+) to resolve this, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          SUM([data]) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, [Year]) AS [data],
          ID, [Year]
FROM TableA
```

If your DBMS not support Window functions, you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          SUM([data]) AS [data],
          ID, [Year]
FROM TableA
GROUP BY ID, [Year]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without keeping a copy is kind of difficult. It is possible though, can't guarantee the performance:

This will update all rows with the new sum and after that delete all rows except 1 for each id combined with year of the date.

```
DECLARE @t table(data decimal(5,2), id int, year date)

INSERT @t
values(1.05, 1, '20151130'),(10, 1, '20151130')

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT
    data, SUM(data) OVER (partition by id, year(year)) new_data
  FROM @t
)
UPDATE CTE SET data = new_data

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT row_number() OVER (partition by id, year(year) ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
  FROM @t
)
DELETE CTE
WHERE rn > 1

SELECT * FROM @t
```